# How to set Image Source property by Xaml Behaviors?

Tags: xaml, uwp, behavior

I want change background image on every FlipView item.
I'm try this code, but it fired error `Only IBehavior types are supported in a BehaviorCollection.`

How set image source correctly?

```
<Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior
            Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=TourFlipView}"
            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
            Value="1" />
        <core:ChangePropertyAction
            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TourFlipViewBackgroundImage}"
            PropertyName="Source"
            Value="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/2.png" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Image
        x:Name="TourFlipViewBackgroundImage"
        Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/1.png" />

    <FlipView
        x:Name="TourFlipView">
        ...
    <FlipView/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did almost correct with small mistake. put your `ChangePropertyAction` inside `DataTriggerBehavior`

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior
        Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=TourFlipView}"
        ComparisonCondition="Equal"
        Value="1" >
        <core:ChangePropertyAction
            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TourFlipViewBackgroundImage}"
            PropertyName="Source"
            Value="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/2.png" />
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior> 
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```